# CNN model stops training after a few epochs, shows no error in Docker logs or VSCode

Tags: docker, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, jupyter

Hi StackOverflow Community,
(This is my first question, so please tell me if I did anything wrong/need to provide more information).

I've tried running an IPYNB I downloaded from my Udacity course, and when I go to run the CNN model, it trains for a few (out of the 100) epochs and then abruptly stops. By a few, I mean 1 or 2, as it varies every time I run it. No errors/warnings are given, and VSCode still shows the cell as running. I also checked the Docker logs, and nothing valuable was there either.

[Here's the link to the Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l05c01_dogs_vs_cats_without_augmentation.ipynb)

The only thing I changed was `model.fit_generator` -> `model.fit` (when I ran with `fit_generator` it told me to change it to fit, as `fit_generator` was going to be deprecated and `model.fit` supports generators.

I also specified to use `/device:GPU:0` when running the model.

This is what that cell looks like with both of those changes:

```py
EPOCHS = 100
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    history = model.fit(
        train_data_gen,
        steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(total_train / float(BATCH_SIZE))),
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        validation_data=val_data_gen,
        validation_steps=int(np.ceil(total_val / float(BATCH_SIZE)))
    )
```

Here's my physical setup:

OS: Windows 11 /
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz /
RAM: 8.0GB /
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti /
VRAM: 6.0GB

WSL setup:

Distro: Ubuntu

Docker setup:

```yaml
version: "1.0"
services:
  jupyter-lab:
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
    environment:
      JUPYTER_TOKEN: "007e1fea040680a3ed5f46b11d61170e2f8132a3a3c45fde"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./TensorFlow:/TensorFlow
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

The TF, TensorRT, and Jupyter versions should all be managed by the latest-gpu-jupyter tag of the image.

After running that cell with the `model.fit`, TensorFlow gave me a few warnings and informations before it started training the model:

```
2023-06-05 01:04:32.760144: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3881 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2023-06-05 01:04:34.831395: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 27000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2023-06-05 01:04:34.975381: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_0' with dtype int32
         [[{{node Placeholder/_0}}]]
2023-06-05 01:04:36.873133: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 27000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2023-06-05 01:04:37.513977: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 27000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2023-06-05 01:04:42.587380: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:424] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
2023-06-05 01:04:49.887547: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:169] XLA service 0x7fc7e572c6c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2023-06-05 01:04:49.887627: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:177]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
2023-06-05 01:04:50.124482: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:269] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
2023-06-05 01:04:50.889217: I ./tensorflow/compiler/jit/device_compiler.h:180] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
2023-06-05 01:05:03.567556: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 27000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2023-06-05 01:05:03.832161: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 27000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2023-06-05 01:05:08.182456: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_0' with dtype int32
         [[{{node Placeholder/_0}}]]
```

Then it quickly runs the first few epochs (in less than a minute) and then stops.

Docker also gave me the error: `WebSocket ping timeout after 92974 ms.`
VSCode shows the cell as still running.

If you have gotten this error before, or possibly know a way to fix it, please let me know, as this problem has been going on for a few days and I don't think it's going to fix if I update anything.

Thanks,
Soumyadeep